# How to fix an animation bug in ApexCharts?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api, apexcharts

I am editing the bar chart provided by ApexCharts, and when I add a border-radius to the bars, the animation during loading or updating breaks, stretching to the left. I'm not sure if this is an error in my options or a bug that needs to be fixed. I have attached an image showing what happens during the animation.

[image]

This is the configuration code I use in my Vue ApexCharts component

```
const series: ApexAxisChartSeries = [
    {
        name: 'series-1',
        data: [70,10, 5,5, 10]
    }
]

const options: ApexOptions = {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        animations: {
            enabled: true
        },
        toolbar: {
            show: false
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: false
        },
        sparkline: {
            enabled: true
        },

    },
    states: {
        hover: {
            filter: {
                type: 'none'
            }
        },
        active: {
            filter: {
                type: 'none'
            }
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            borderRadius: 4,
            columnWidth: 41,
            distributed: true,
            rangeBarOverlap: true,
            colors: {
                backgroundBarOpacity: 0.3,
                backgroundBarColors: arrayOfColors,
                backgroundBarRadius: 4
            },
            borderRadiusApplication: 'around'
        }
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    colors: arrayOfColors,
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },

    legend: {
        show: false,
    },
    grid: {
        show: false,
    },

    xaxis: {
        axisTicks: { show: false },
        labels: {
            show: false
        },

        axisBorder: { show: false },
        categories: [`a`, 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    },
    yaxis: {
        show: false,
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    }
}
```

template:

```
<apexchart width="252" height="120"  :options="options" :series="series"> </apexchart>
```